# How to make tab active when application load using tabset?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When my application loads first time it loads `app.dit` page but tab does not show active once you start clicking on tabs it works after that, So I want to make first tab `DIT` active when application load. How can i achieve that task with below code ?

main.html

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
                <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" select="go(tab.route)" heading="{{tab.heading}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
                    <!--<div ui-view="">{{tab.route}}</div>-->
                </uib-tab>
            </uib-tabset>
```

ctrl.js

```
 $scope.tabs = [{
       heading: 'DIT',
       route: 'app.dit',
       active: true
   }, {
       heading: 'ST',
       route: 'app.st',
       active: false
   }, {
       heading: 'UAT',
       route: 'app.uat',
       active: false
   }, ];

   $scope.go = function(route) {
       $state.go(route);
   };

   function active(route) {
       return $state.is(route);
   }
   $scope.active = active;

   $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
       $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
           tab.active = active(tab.route);
       });
   });
```

app.js

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
      var $state = $injector.get('$state');
      $state.go('app.dit');
  });

  $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
          abstract: true,
          url: '',
          templateUrl: 'web/global/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .state('app.dit', {
          url: '/dit',
          templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
          controller: 'DitCtrl'
      })
      .state('app.st', {
          url: '/st',
          templateUrl: 'view/partials/st.html',
          controller: 'StCtrl'
      })
      .state('app.uat', {
          url: '/uat',
          templateUrl: 'view/partials/uat.html',
          controller: 'UatCtrl'
      })
      .state('app.prod', {
          url: '/prod',
          templateUrl: 'view/partials/prod.html',
          controller: 'ProdCtrl',
      })
```

;

Comment: i don't see why you need `<uib-tabs>` at all when all you are doing is using them for navigation. Wouldn't it be  a lot simpler just using tabs html and `ui-sref` and `ui-sref-active` for the links?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you're doing wrong with code you shared... Can you post a minimal fiddler, plunkr or something similar?

Comment: @charliefl that was my thought as well, but my requirement enforcing  me to use uib-tabs.

Comment: @Robert sorry dont have access to jsfiddle etc, i have listed everything related to issue

Comment: I don't get it...can achieve exactly the same display and make it simpler without using them. Can still render each tab from array so template html wouldn't be any larger

Comment: i know but i have no choice other than uib-tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tabs/docs), the `active` variable bound in `<uib-tabset active="active">` must be the index of the tab you want to show as active.

Setting the `$scope.active` variable to 0 (or to whichever index you wish) in your controller should help.

---

Additionally, it may be better for you to instead dynamically set the `$scope.active` variable straight away based on your current $state (instead of relying on an `active` bool for each tab and manipulating it during `$stateChangeSuccess`, which might run the risk of showing 2+ active tabs).

```
var returnActiveTabIndex = function() {
    var current_route = $state.$current.name;  //or however you want to find your current $state
    var tab_routes = $scope.tabs.map(function(tab) { return tab.route });

    var active_index = tab_routes.indexOf(current_route);
    return (active_index > -1) ? active_index : 0;
};

$scope.active = returnActiveTabIndex();
```

Added benefit is after browser reload, the CTRL will read your current state (for example, "app.st") and set the "app.st" tab to active based on the matched route.